Summarising data into groups based on rules
I have a dataset of governorates, crops and areas. Each crop can be grown in 1 of 3 seasons. In reality, crops are grown in combination, with 1, 2 or 3 crops per year. I would like to come up with the minimum number of combinations that could be used to describe the data. Combinations should be prioritised to maximise 3 crop combinations, then 2 crop combinations then 1 crop combinations. The total area for each crop and governorate cannot be greater than the table below. The area of the combination would be the same as the area of each crop in that combination. A crop from a governorate and season can be in multiple combinations. The table is a sample of data.
   Governorates Season Crop                        Area
   <chr>        <chr>  <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 Alexandria   Winter Wheat.                    65713 
 2 Alexandria   Winter Legumes.                  14506 
 3 Alexandria   Winter Fiber.crops.                  0 
 4 Alexandria   Winter Other.field.crops.        48872 
 5 Alexandria   Winter Fodder.seasonal.          42194 
 6 Alexandria   Winter Medical.aromatic.plants.  14846.
 7 Alexandria   Winter Main.vegetables.           1704.
 8 Alexandria   Winter Other.vegetables.         22172.
 9 Assuit       Winter Wheat.                   164483 
10 Assuit       Winter Legumes.                  21914 
11 Assuit       Winter Fiber.crops.                  0 
12 Assuit       Winter Other.field.crops.       109106 
13 Assuit       Winter Fodder.seasonal.         101602 
14 Assuit       Winter Medical.aromatic.plants.   7532 
15 Assuit       Winter Main.vegetables.          10121 
16 Assuit       Winter Other.vegetables.          3316 
17 Aswan        Winter Wheat.                    52964 
18 Aswan        Winter Legumes.                   3693 
19 Aswan        Winter Fiber.crops.                  0 
20 Aswan        Winter Other.field.crops.        13398 
21 Alexandria   Summer Maize.                    30575 
22 Alexandria   Summer Rice.                       169 
23 Alexandria   Summer Fiber.crops.               4194 
24 Alexandria   Summer Oil.crops.                 2118 
25 Alexandria   Summer Other.field.crops.        10491 
26 Alexandria   Summer Fodder.seasonal.          10289 
27 Alexandria   Summer Medical.aromatic.plants.  19245 
28 Alexandria   Summer Main.vegetables.          43335 
29 Alexandria   Summer Other.vegetables.         57822 
30 Assuit       Summer Maize.                   136062 
31 Assuit       Summer Rice.                         0 
32 Assuit       Summer Fiber.crops.               6465 
33 Assuit       Summer Oil.crops.                13628 
34 Assuit       Summer Other.field.crops.       123560 
35 Assuit       Summer Fodder.seasonal.          15024 
36 Assuit       Summer Medical.aromatic.plants.   5996 
37 Assuit       Summer Main.vegetables.           4192 
38 Assuit       Summer Other.vegetables.         15039 
39 Aswan        Summer Maize.                     9180 
40 Aswan        Summer Rice.                         0 
41 Alexandria   Nile   Maize.                    11467 
42 Alexandria   Nile   Rice.                         0 
43 Alexandria   Nile   Oil.crops.                    0 
44 Alexandria   Nile   Other.field.crops.         1067 
45 Alexandria   Nile   Fodder.seasonal.           1067 
46 Alexandria   Nile   Medical.aromatic.plants.   3666.
47 Alexandria   Nile   Main.vegetables.            931 
48 Alexandria   Nile   Other.vegetables.          5451.
49 Assuit       Nile   Maize.                        0 
50 Assuit       Nile   Rice.                         0 
51 Assuit       Nile   Oil.crops.                    0 
52 Assuit       Nile   Other.field.crops.            0 
53 Assuit       Nile   Fodder.seasonal.              0 
54 Assuit       Nile   Medical.aromatic.plants.      0 
55 Assuit       Nile   Main.vegetables.              0 
56 Assuit       Nile   Other.vegetables.           663 
57 Aswan        Nile   Maize.                     3310 
58 Aswan        Nile   Rice.                         0 
59 Aswan        Nile   Oil.crops.                  214 
60 Aswan        Nile   Other.field.crops.         5900 

I tried linear progamming, but am unsure this is the right way to go. Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code I tried:
f.obj <- rep(1,nrow(combined_df_long))

f.con <- 
  matrix(c(rep(1,nrow(combined_df_long)),
           (combined_df_long$Season=="Winter") *1.0,
           (combined_df_long$Season=="Summer") *1.0,
           (combined_df_long$Season=="Nile") *1.0,
           ),nrow=4,byrow= TRUE)

f.dir <- c("<=", "==","<=","<=")

f.rhs<- c(3, #no.of crops
          1 , #Winter
          1 , # Summer
          1  # Nile
)


solutions <-   lp ("min", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs,all.bin=TRUE) 

Thanks
Edit:
Here is the dput combined_df_long:
"Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", 
"Assuit", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", 
"Aswan", "Aswan", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", 
"Assuit", "Assuit", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", 
"Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Alexandria", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", 
"Assuit", "Assuit", "Assuit", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", 
"Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan", "Aswan"), Season = c("Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", 
"Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", 
"Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", 
"Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile", "Nile"
), Crop = c("Wheat.", "Legumes.", "Fiber.crops.", "Other.field.crops.", 
"Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", "Main.vegetables.", 
"Other.vegetables.", "Wheat.", "Legumes.", "Fiber.crops.", "Other.field.crops.", 
"Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", "Main.vegetables.", 
"Other.vegetables.", "Wheat.", "Legumes.", "Fiber.crops.", "Other.field.crops.", 
"Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", "Main.vegetables.", 
"Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Fiber.crops.", "Oil.crops.", 
"Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Fiber.crops.", 
"Oil.crops.", "Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Fiber.crops.", 
"Oil.crops.", "Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Oil.crops.", 
"Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Oil.crops.", 
"Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables.", "Maize.", "Rice.", "Oil.crops.", 
"Other.field.crops.", "Fodder.seasonal.", "Medical.aromatic.plants.", 
"Main.vegetables.", "Other.vegetables."), Area = c(65713, 14506, 
0, 48872, 42194, 14846.1428571429, 1704.05714285714, 22172.2, 
164483, 21914, 0, 109106, 101602, 7532, 10121, 3316, 52964, 3693, 
0, 13398, 10918, 3450, 2517, 5725, 30575, 169, 4194, 2118, 10491, 
10289, 19245, 43335, 57822, 136062, 0, 6465, 13628, 123560, 15024, 
5996, 4192, 15039, 9180, 0, 0, 7873, 20724, 5011, 11588, 689, 
4346, 11467, 0, 0, 1067, 1067, 3665.71428571429, 931, 5450.71428571429, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 663, 3310, 0, 214, 5900, 965, 1558, 351, 
1172)), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

In terms of output it would be a dataframe similar to the table below. Combinations could also be divided into 3 columns, 1 for each season. The values in area are not accurate.
   Governorates                            Combination Area
1    Alexandria          Wheat-Maize-Other.field.crops 1211
2    Alexandria            Wheat-Maize-Main.vegetables 1000
3    Alexandria                  Wheat-Main.vegetables  700
4    Alexandria Main.vegtables-Medical.aromatic.plants  500
5        Assuit          Wheat-Maize-Other.field.crops 2000
6        Assuit            Wheat-Maize-Main.vegetables 1000
7        Assuit                  Wheat-Main.vegetables  400
8         Aswan          Wheat-Maize-Other.field.crops 1500
9         Aswan            Wheat-Maize-Main.vegetables 1000
10        Aswan                  Wheat-Main.vegetables  200

